# How can I prevent Redactor italicising text within asterisks?

Tags: redactor

In my Rich Text field,  I've got some text that looks like this (it uses an unordered list):

```
• Line 1
• Line 2*
• Line 3

* Here is some more text
```

The problem is that the "Line 3" text is appearing in italics, and neither of the asterisks display in the page preview.

Is there a way I can stop this from happening? Perhaps there's an escape character to use in this situation?